# Copying file data over network using Java very slow

Tags: java, networking

My code has to read a portion of data from each file it loads, typically about 100,000 bytes. This works fine for local files but can be really slow over my wifi network, even though my network seems adequate (but not blistering fast)

So I created this simple test:

```
public void testDataCopySpeed() throws Exception
    {
        File file = new File("Z:\\TestFile.mp3");
        System.out.println("start:"+new Date());
        FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(500000);         //1/2 MB
        fc.read(bb);
        System.out.println("end:"+new Date());
    }
```

Would take less than a second on  a local file, but over a minute on a networked file.

So I then tried to test my network speed, I cannot see how to just test the wifi but I tested the internet upload/download speed using http://myspeedtestonline.com/ assuming this would be slower than my actual wifi network. It gave me:

Download Speed:512KB/second
Upload Speed  :40KB/second

and I ran the same test on another computer and it gave a similar speed

So how is it I can download 1/2 MB of data in one second but it can take a minute to copy 1/2MB of data from one file in Java, the file is hosted on a NAS. ?

EDIT:So I have a couple of good answers below, what I really want to know is what is the best way to get access to the first 100,000 bytes from a set of files for read only access that will work for local and networked files, or should I have different code depending on whether or not it is not networked. Fixing the network is not really the solution, I may be able to fix my network but this software has to work on any computer, many of my customer may not have optiminal networks and would not have the skill to fix their network issues.

Comment: How fast can you copy the file using Windows Explorer? Maybe your file server is just very slow...

Comment: Took 4 seconds to copy over the whole 6mb file

Comment: Righto, that suggests it really is in how Java talks to the file system somewhere.

Comment: So you have mounted your NAS and read this via a network mount right?

Comment: what is a *networked file*? are you copying to your NAS? is it in your local network? is copying with `cp` or `copy` faster?

Comment: No copying data from a file on my NAS from my PC

Comment: have you tried reading without a `channel`? just with `BufferedInputStream.read()`

Comment: No, because I want the data in a single buffer, if I use BufferedInputStream asn the internal buffer gets filled up Im going to lose access to the start of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try a memory mapped file?

```
File file = new File("Z:/TestFile.mp3");
System.out.println("start:"+new Date());
FileChannel fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, fc.size());
System.out.println("end:"+new Date());
```

This might only appear faster, or it may help hide how long it takes.

Comment: heh, just been doing this independently myself, and it is quite a bit faster, but why is that ?

Comment: It only loads the data as you access it. It means it can be download in parallel with use or only the portions you use are downloaded.

Comment: Right, so if I then go ahead and actually need to use all the data that I have copied (which I do) then wont be such an improvement but because transferring smaller units there might be less transmission errors. So Mmapped does still copy data from file to buffer, I was thinking this step wasn't needed.

Comment: The data is notionally available "immediately" No extra steps are required, however the OS automagically pulls in the pages you use, as you use them.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples with oranges here. When you access http://myspeedtestonline.com/, the flash plugin is probably using the HTTP protocol, but certainly not CIFS.

When you address a file on a NAS, it's most probably using the CIFS protocol. This protocol is known to have performance problems, especially when implemented on consumer appliances (Buffalo drives, etc.).

Sometimes the MTU size is too big, causing the packets to be fragmented and resent.

So my guess is that Java is not the right address to blame in this case. In any case however, you cannot analyze the problem with a simple Java program. You should use a network sniffer for this.

Comment: Well the problem is with the Java program, that is what Im trying to improve, it seems to be okay just using Windows. but are you saying by trying to copy 500,000 bytes Java tries to do that in one go, and too often it loses bytes and has to be retransmitted whereas when using FileExplorer it breaks it inot smaller bits that are less likely to need retransmitting.

Comment: I wondered about using FileChannel.transferTo(long position,long count,WritableByteChannel target), maybe it does somthing clever under the hood but I cant see how to get a WritableByteChannel from a ByteBuffer as I want to copy the data to a buffer not another file.

Comment: No I mean network transmission. The Java App is somewhat at layer 7 of the OSI layer. But the packet transmission is somewhere at layer 4. You cannot observe these layers in the Java application.